# Импорт класса из другого файла

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Я имею файл **main.py** в котором есть код:

```py
import pygame
import os
import sys
import random as rand
from player import Player


def load_image(name, colorkey=None):
    fullname = os.path.join('data', name)
    # если файл не существует, то выходим
    if not os.path.isfile(fullname):
        print(f"Файл с изображением '{fullname}' не найден")
        sys.exit()
    image = pygame.image.load(fullname)
    if colorkey is not None:
        image = image.convert()
        if colorkey == -1:
            colorkey = image.get_at((0, 0))
        image.set_colorkey(colorkey)
    else:
        image = image.convert_alpha()
    return image


pygame.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('Battle City')
size = (500, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
FPS = 60
width = height = 25
player = None
enemies = []
all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
tiles_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
enemy_group = pygame.sprite.Group()
tile_images = {
    'wall': load_image('wall.png'),
    'empty': load_image('empty.png'),
    'iron-wall': load_image('iron-wall.png'),
    'water': load_image('water.png'),
    'base': load_image('base.png'),
    'star': load_image('star.png'),
    'grenade': load_image('grenade.png'),
    'shovel': load_image('shovel.png')
}
player_image = load_image('player.png')
enemy_image = load_image("enemy1.png")
bullet_image = load_image('bullet.png')

tile_width = tile_height = 20


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, pos_x, pos_y, health, speed):
        super().__init__(player_group, all_sprites)
        self.image = player_image
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect().move(
            tile_width * pos_x, tile_height * pos_y)
        self.x, self.y = pos_x, pos_y
        self.angle = 0
        self.top = self.down = self.left = self.right = False
        self.last_direction = "top"
        self.tile_type = "player"
        self.hp = health
        self.speed = speed
        self.damage = 5
        self.died = False

    def get_position(self):
        return self.rect.x, self.rect.y

    def move(self):
        if self.left:
            self.rotate_player("left")
            self.rect.x -= self.speed
        elif self.right:
            self.rotate_player("right")
            self.rect.x += self.speed
        elif self.top:
            self.rotate_player("top")
            self.rect.y -= self.speed
        elif self.down:
            self.rotate_player("down")
            self.rect.y += self.speed

    def rotate_player(self, side):
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, -self.angle)
        self.angle = 0
        if side == "left":
            self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, 90)
            self.angle += 90
        elif side == "right":
            self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, 270)
            self.angle += 270
        elif side == "top":
            pass
        elif side == "down":
            self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, 180)
            self.angle += 180
        self.last_direction = side

    def check_position(self):
        if self.rect.x < 0:
            self.left = False
            self.rect.x += 1
        elif self.rect.x + 20 > size[0]:
            self.right = False
            self.rect.x -= 1
        elif self.rect.y < 0:
            self.top = False
            self.rect.y += 1
        elif self.rect.y + 20 > size[1]:
            self.down = False
            self.rect.y -= 1

    def check_collision(self):
        for sprite in all_sprites:
            if pygame.Rect.colliderect(self.rect, sprite.rect) and sprite.tile_type in \
                    ("wall", "iron-wall", "water", "base", "grenade", "shovel", "star", "enemy"):
                if self.last_direction == "left":
                    self.rect.x += 1
                    self.left = False
                elif self.last_direction == "right":
                    self.rect.x -= 1
                    self.right = False
                elif self.last_direction == "top":
                    self.rect.y += 1
                    self.top = False
                elif self.last_direction == "down":
                    self.rect.y -= 1
                    self.down = False

    def death(self, damage):
        self.hp -= damage
        if self.hp <= 0:
            self.died = True

    def update(self, *args):
        screen.blit(self.image, (self.rect.x, self.rect.y))
        if args and args[0].type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if args[0].key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.left = True
            elif args[0].key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.right = True
            elif args[0].key == pygame.K_UP:
                self.top = True
            elif args[0].key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                self.down = True
        elif args and args[0].type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if args[0].key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                self.left = False
            elif args[0].key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                self.right = False
            elif args[0].key == pygame.K_UP:
                self.top = False
            elif args[0].key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                self.down = False
        self.check_position()
        self.check_collision()
        self.move()
```

Мне нужно перенести оттуда класс `Player` в другой файл. Проблема в том, что в классе используются переменные которые определяются до него, и мне бы не хотелось переписывать эти переменные в новый файл тоже.

Каким образом можно правильно вынести класс `Player` в другой файл для дальнейшего импорта?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думается мне, что лучше будет сделать так:

**vars.py**
`#ваши переменные, которые вы не хотите переписывать`

**player.py**
`#class Player(): ....`

**main.py**

```
from player import Player
from vars import *
...
```

Comment: Спасибо!Для того, чтобы все заработало я добавил from vars import * еще и в файл player.py